# How to propagate Open Telemetry span to Executor threads in Spring Boot (or Is it possible for the span to exist in THREAD_LOCAL mode)

Tags: java, thread-local, open-telemetry

I am trying to set up an open telemetry tracer to propagate to thread, spawned by the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor which is configured as follows

```
private DgsDataLoaderAsyncExecutor() {
  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
  executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
  executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
  executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
  executor.setThreadNamePrefix("threadAsync");
  executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
  executor.setTaskDecorator(new DataLoaderTaskDecorator());
  executor.initialize();
  executorInstance = executor;
  // spring tracer is obtained here to extract the current span later on 
  tracer = GlobalOpenTelemetry.getTracer("org.springframework.boot");
}
```

Later on I call the executor as such:

```
/**
 * Only one (or no) Executor will live in the service at all times. It will be retrieved in a thread safe manner
 * @return executor to be used in the DataLoader
 */
public static synchronized Executor get() {
  if (instance == null) {
    instance = new DgsDataLoaderAsyncExecutor();
  }
  return instance.getExecutorInstance();
}

static class DataLoaderTaskDecorator implements TaskDecorator {
  /**
   * Currently, tenant, security, and locale contexts are passed
   */
  @Override
  public Runnable decorate(Runnable runnable) {
    // Current Web Thread context to be passed ot async
    var currentSpanContext = Context.current();
    var currentSpan = Span.current();
    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();

    log.debug("Saving information for async thread...");
    return () -> {
      // this span shows up in the parent trace as expected 
      Span asyncSpan = tracer.spanBuilder("DGS Executor async op")
        .setParent(currentSpanContext.with(currentSpan))
        .startSpan();
      try {
        // Async thread context
        LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(locale);
        log.debug("Restoring information for async thread...");
        // however the spans in the thread fail to obtain the parent trace and are not linked to it
        runnable.run();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error in async task", e);
      } finally {
        asyncSpan.end();
        log.debug("DgsDataLoader has finished async execution");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

However the span fails to propagate to the thread and a new parent is created for the spans that are created in that thread.

I have been able to get around that by creating a custom context where I pack the the current span

```
Span asyncSpan = tracer.spanBuilder("DGS Executor async op")
  .setParent(currentSpanContext.with(currentSpan))
  .startSpan();
try {
  SpanThreadContextHolder.setTracingSpan(asyncSpan);
  // Async thread context
  LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(locale);
  log.debug("Restoring information for async thread...");
  runnable.run();
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("Error in async task", e);
} finally {
  SpanThreadContextHolder.removeTracingSpan();
```

but that comes with a side effect where the downstream code has to be aware of it and activate it through

```
// inside runnable.run()
var span = SpanThreadContextHolder.getOpenTracingSpan()
if (span!= null) {
    Context.current().with(span).makeCurrent()
}
```

With all this story done, my question is:
is it possible to automatically propagate the span to the other threads spawned from the master thread, having the span exist in a THREAD_LOCAL mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have eventually found the answer [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues/6201).

The executor has to be wrapped with otel context:

```
public ExecutorService wrapExecutor(ExecutorService executor) {
  return Context.taskWrapping(executor);
}
```